# How to split different hosted zones per environment/AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-acm

Is it possible to create hosted zones on different accounts using the same domain name ?

AWS Account for production:

```
Certificat *.mywebsite.com
hosted zone mywebsite.com
record api.mywebsite.com
```

AWS Account for development:

```
Certificate *.dev.mywebsite.com
hosted zone dev.mywebsite.com
record api.dev.mywebsite.com
```

If everything works fine on the production account, my `api.dev.mywebsite.com` record still in `Pending Validation` status.

I am wondering if we really can split hosted zones this way, maybe there is like a conflict between the hosted zones of the two environments? How can we separate development and production environments properly with AWS Account?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, we can split this way but we have to create an NS record on the production Account referencing the development NS values